# simple linear regression notation

Tags: regression, linear-model

> [image]

Here is the capture from my lecture notes, and I am so confused with that notations.

For **Several normal samples**, can anyone show me how to write $x_{ij}$ in terms of vector form
(involving $p$) and claim that $x_{ij}=0$ if $i\notin j$, otherwise $x_{ij}=1$

Moreover, for **Simple linear regression**, what's the point of indexing explanatory variables with the observed value, for different observed value, aren't they share the same explanatory variables.

Much appreciated for any comments.

Comment: Hi: For your second question, they share the same explanatory variables but the VALUE is different. $(y_{j}, x_{j})$ is not the same as $(y_{j}, x_{i})$. Unfortunately, I don't understand your first question.

Comment: @mlofton cheers, you are right